# identifying and removing legends from ggplot objects

Tags: r, ggplot2

i am using autoplot from survMisc package which generates a ggplot survival curve.
i then add a geom_line object and this causes a duplicate legend to be produced. 
[image]

```
data(kidney, package="KMsurv")
s1 <- survfit(Surv(time, delta)~1 , data=kidney)
p1<-autoplot(s1, type="fill", survLineSize=2)
d1=data.frame(x=seq(0,20,10),y=seq(0,1,.5),lab=rep('lin'))
p1$plot+geom_line(data=d1,aes_string(x='x',y='y', colour='lab'),inherit.aes=F)
```

reading [r cookbook](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/) 
it seems to suggest I should override using scale_XXX_discrete for xxx = colour/fill/... according to what was used.  Now how do I find out what was used by autoplot? is there a simple way of identifying the legend source (and the label used - eg is it 1, or '1')?

I tried adding

```
  + scale_colour_discrete(name='Estimate',
                      breaks=c(1,'lin'),
                      labels=c('observed','lin')) +
 scale_fill_discrete(name='Estimate',
                    breaks=c(1,'lin'),
                    labels=c('observed','lin')) +
```

and it changed the 1 to 'observed' but I still have a duplicate legend

```
p1$plot$scales
Reference class object of class "Scales"
Field "scales":
[[1]]
discrete_scale(aesthetics = "colour", scale_name = "brewer", 
    palette = brewer_pal(type, palette), guide = ..1)

[[2]]
discrete_scale(aesthetics = "fill", scale_name = "brewer", palette =    brewer_pal(type, 
palette), guide = ..1)

[[3]]
continuous_scale(aesthetics = c("y", "ymin", "ymax", "yend", 
"yintercept", "ymin_final", "ymax_final"), scale_name = "position_c", 
palette = identity, name = ..1, expand = expand, guide = "none")

[[4]]
continuous_scale(aesthetics = c("x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend", 
"xintercept"), scale_name = "position_c", palette = identity, 
name = ..1, breaks = ..2, expand = expand, guide = "none")
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `guide = "none"` to `geom_line`?

Comment: i just tried   p1$plot+geom_line(data=d1,aes_string(x='x',y='y', colour='lab'),inherit.aes=F, guide='none'), but that still gives me two legends  and I wouldn't expect it to work.. I want to have the labels from autoplot and geom lines but just in a single legend box

Comment: I loaded KMsurv, ggplot2 and survival and I'm unable to make autoplot work. It won't accept a survfit object. Can you make the question reproducible?

Comment: can you try survMisc::autoplot [i think it depends on the order you load these in ggplot2 then survMisc]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the code for `survMisc:::autoplot.survfit` you'll see that there are two scales being set: `scale_colour_brewer` and `scale_fill_brewer`.  In the code you've posted only the `colour` scale is being affected by the additional `geom_line` layer.  To have a single legend you'll want to handle the `fill` scale as well.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(survMisc)
library(KMsurv)

data(kidney, package="KMsurv")

s1 <- survfit(Surv(time, delta) ~ 1 , data = kidney)
p1 <- autoplot(s1, type = "fill", survLineSize = 2)
d1 <- data.frame(x = seq(0,20,10), y = seq(0,1,.5), lab = rep('lin'))

p1$plot + 
  geom_line(data = d1,
            aes_string(x = 'x',y = 'y', fill = 'lab',  colour = 'lab'),
            inherit.aes=F)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! I had noticed the two scales by probing the object (my clumsy scale_fill etc), your answer makes sense